# How can I use flexbox to create 3 boxes in each of the two rows?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to match the design below. I have nearly completed my project, I just need to create the section where there are 6 boxes with different colors as shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4wij.jpg)

Currently you can see what I have in the codepen below
https://codepen.io/JoyFulCoding/pen/EzWyKv

I need a section as shown above where there are 6 boxes spread across two rows i.e. there are 3 boxes in each row

```css
#container-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container-parent>div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="container-parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

I thought the above would work after following this:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-direction_row

etc. but it is not working. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated thank you.

https://codepen.io/JoyFulCoding/pen/EzWyKv

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are targeting the right elements, avoid confusing classes (`.container-parent`) with ids (`#container-parent`);

The `flex-direction: row` is not needed, since `row` is the default value for the property; also consider using the `flex` property as well, shorthand for: `flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis`; which will help you setup the behavior and size you want your flex items to have.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container-parent {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container-parent>div {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100px;
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section id="container-parent">
  <div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>
</section>
```

For your issue regarding the centered text, try changing your rule with this:

```
#container-parent>div {
  display:flex;
  color:white;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 350px;
  flex: 1 0 33%; 
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family:"Raleway" , sans-seriff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this resolves my confusion. To prevent another question from being asked may I ask how can you place text in the center of each box? In my codepen here: https://codepen.io/JoyFulCoding/pen/EzWyKv I tried writing ''Facebook <br/> Ad Campaigns" in the first box but this causes the Ad Campaigns words to miss multiple lines as shown in the codepen above. Confusing...

Comment: I would suggest either relying on paddings to push the content to the center, or make the item a flex container as well, set it to `flex-direction: column` and then you can use `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` in the item css and it will center everything really well

Comment: Yes I have tried using justify-content : center and align-items: center as well as flex-direction: column but it is still not working? Please check it here https://codepen.io/JoyFulCoding/pen/EzWyKv

Comment: I added those rules and it worked fine; but you also had a `display: inline-block` in the same place, which overrides the `display: flex` set before... Check the piece of code I added on the answer

Comment: Hello J,

Pls check this pen, Just added a little CSS rule to your css and its done.
https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/pmPZev 

And one more thing, there is white line in box below text, You have put a div there for that, that's not the right way to create such things, Why to add an extra HTML element when you can achieve the same by just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by id="container-parent"

```
<section id="container-parent">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="p-2 flex-column col-4">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2  flex-column col-4">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2  flex-column col-4">Flex item 3</div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="p-2 bg-info  flex-column col-4">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bg-warning  flex-column col-4">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bg-primary  flex-column col-4">Flex item 3</div>
</div>

    </section>
```

css

```
#container-parent {
    background-color: red;
}
```

add this in head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

[Here is one good example](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/?example=/css/flexbox/examples/flexbox_nested_grid_1)!
Hope it helps you

Comment: To prevent another question from being asked may I ask how can you place text in the center of each box? In my codepen here: codepen.io/JoyFulCoding/pen/EzWyKv I tried writing ''Facebook <br/> Ad Campaigns" in the first box but this causes the Ad Campaigns words to miss multiple lines as shown in the codepen above. Confusing...

Comment: Hello J, Pls check this pen, Just added a little CSS rule to your css and its done. https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/pmPZev